# React-leaflet. Stop propagation when click on a drawn polygon

Tags: react-leaflet, leaflet.draw

```
<Map center={center} zoom={13} onClick={this._onMapClick}>
    <FeatureGroup color="purple" onClick={this._onClick}>
      <EditControl
          position='topright'
          draw={{
              rectangle: false,
              polyline: false,
              circle: false,
              marker: false,
              circlemarker: false
          }}
    />
</Map>
```

I use **react-leaflet** and **react-leaflet-draw** to draw polygon on the map. I want to click on the drawn polygon to do something. But I found that click event fired on both polygon and map(Both _onClick and _onMapClick fired.). What can I do to prevent the propagation?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this after a bit of debugging using the developer tools.

I had to call stopPropagation() that's held within the Leaflet object.

```
_onClick(e){
  e.originalEvent.view.L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your event handlers will get an event, check the target of the event and if it's a polygon any other react-leaflet-draw layer 
you can prevent it inside _onMapClick

so something like that (pseudo code)

```
_onMapClick(e){
   var layer = e.target;
   if(layer == Your Draw Layer){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your kindly help. But unfortunately, it doesn't work.
Error occured: Uncaught TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation` to disable scrolling propagation
- `DomEvent.disableClickPropagation` to disable click propapagation

Example:

```
const divContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
useEffect(() => {
    if(divContainer.current) {
        DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(divContainer.current);
        DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(divContainer.current);
    }
});
...
return (
    <div ref={divContainer}>
...
```